# What happened when the spies were sent out to Canaan?

Tags: deuteronomy, moses, canaan

In Deuteronomy 1:22 it says:

> But all of you came to me and said, ‘Let’s send some men to look at
> the land first. They can spy out the land and come back and tell us
> the way  we should go and which cities we will come to.

In Numbers 13:1, 2 though there is a different account:

> The Lord said to Moses, “Send some men to explore the land of Canaan,
> which I am giving to the Israelites. From each ancestral tribe send
> one of its leaders.”

So which account is correct, did the LORD tell Moses to send spies out into the land of Canaan or did the people tell Moses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that both accounts are correct.  That is, the people's lack of faith demanded that the land be spied out before the looming conquest.  Then when Moses presented this request to the LORD, He set out the best way for this to be done.

Ellicott offers this comment on Num 13:1

> (1) **And the Lord spake unto Moses** . . . —There is no inconsistency
> between this statement and that which is contained in Deuteronomy
> 1:22, where the sending of the spies is represented as having
> originated with the people. It is there said that the saying pleased
> Moses well; but it would be wholly inconsistent with the character and
> conduct of Moses to suppose that in a matter of such importance he
> should have acted in a accordance with the suggestion of the people,
> or upon his own judgment, without seeking direction from God. The
> command which was given to Moses must not be regarded as implying of
> necessity that the expedition of the spies was, in the first instance,
> ordained by God, any more than the command which was afterwards given
> to Balaam to accompany the messengers of Balak was any indication that
> God originally commanded, or approved of his journey.